# XML Parsing not Working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, activexobject, domparser

For an XML string such as:

```
var xml_string = '<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   <env:Header/>   <env:Body>      <dn:response id="?" xmlns:dn="http://www.datanomic.com/ws">         <dn:record>            <dn:Result>John</dn:Result>         </dn:record>         <dn:record>            <dn:Result>Johnghghg</dn:Result>         </dn:record>         <dn:record>            <dn:Result>Johnn</dn:Result>         </dn:record>         <dn:record>            <dn:Result>Johnngy</dn:Result>         </dn:record>         <dn:record>            <dn:Result>Johnnnn</dn:Result>         </dn:record>         <dn:record>            <dn:Result>Johnny</dn:Result>         </dn:record>         <dn:record>            <dn:Result>Johns</dn:Result>         </dn:record>         <dn:record>            <dn:Result>Johnson</dn:Result>         </dn:record>         <dn:record>            <dn:Result>Johnston</dn:Result>         </dn:record>      </dn:response>   </env:Body></env:Envelope>';
```

I'm using the following code (obtained from SO itself)

```
if (window.DOMParser)
  {
    parser=new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xml_string,"text/xml");
  }
else // Internet Explorer
  {
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(xml_string);
  }
  var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("dn:Result");
  console.log(nodes); // returning empty on Chrome, working fine in Firefox and IE10
```

If I remove the `dn:` from `getElementsByTagName`, it starts to work in Chrome but not in Firefox and IE. So is there a solution for it to work in all 3 
browsers?

Here is the fiddle for ease of testing: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LzxLukg2/)

PS: jQuery isn't an option. I'm hoping this could be done via plain old Javascript alone.

Comment: hate to tell you, but works in Firefox 42, doesn't work in Firefox 44

Comment: Isn't 42 the latest version? I guess you're using a beta version?

Comment: Developer version - stay 6 to 12 weeks ahead of changes like this :p

Comment: I would suggest ... get "Results" and if that returns 0 length collection, get "dn:Results" ... I recommend in that order as ... chrome + firefox (next or one after version) + Edge all work with "Result" ... so,

Comment: Thanks. That's one way of solving it. But let's see if someone posts an alternative way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use the W3C DOM Level 2 method `getElementsByTagNameNS` where available, see http://jsfiddle.net/bygx406g/, which changes one line to

```
var nodes = typeof xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS != 'undefined' ? xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.datanomic.com/ws', 'Result') : xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("dn:Result");
```

Comment: It could be noted that the `'*'` name-space value will match any namespace, no need to write it down every time if the tagName is not present in multiple namespaces. This can be useful for lazy guys like me.